# CheckBoxPreference List

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-studio

I'm trying to write an android app.
I have a settings activity, which has all the preferences.
Currently, I'm want to have a similar hierarchy to this:

```
 - Group 1 (Checkbox):
      Option 1
      Option 2
 - Group 2 (simple category, no checkbox):
      Option 3
      Option 4
```

In this hierarchy, how can I do categories, that if group 1 checkbox isn't checked, both options 1 and 2 are disabled, and option 3 is disabled too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what have you actually tried?

Comment: have you tried implementing it? If, yes then where are you stuck? the value of prefs are stored using sharedPref ryt with key which you have specified and the value in your case true or false.So, when you are changing the checkbox of any group, you can also the value of other group.Better you create a listener.

Comment: @redFIVE I didn't find a way to create a category which is also a textbox..

Comment: what about EditTextPreference?

Comment: @Ritesh How is this helping me? The name of the category is predefined. All I wanted is to be showed and to be able to turn it on/off

Comment: Like i mentioned above, create a listener for your preferenceActivity and onChange on any group you can change the value or say turn it on/off of other as per your requirement. Do you want complete code for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you need exactly but this might help :

```
if (yourCheckBoxView.isChecked()){

            yourOptionView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // or
            yourOptionView.setEnabled(true);

        } else {

            yourOptionView.setEnabled(false);
            // or
            yourOptionView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
```

Is this what you want ? If so, do you want the full code ? And what type of View are your options ?